# How to set linux server so the URL is passed through a single php template file?

Tags: php, web-hosting

I am making a template for a website and want every page to be passed through a single php file to allow for both easy page editing and elegant, intuitive URLs. I have a standard Linux webhosting package and want so that when the user visits `http://example.com/language-x/a-page-called-foo` then the sever invokes and returns the output from `http://example.com/template.php?page=a-page-called-foo&language=language-x` without the user seeing anything to do with tamplate.php in the address bar. Is there some standard way to do this so I don't have to contact my webhosting provider and asking for them to tweak the way the server is working?

Comment: you can use htaccess to rewrite your urls

Comment: hi @baao , any chance you could be  more specific? I've never done anything with htaccess before. I want my template system to be clean and simple and so do not want to have to make a new folder for every page. can I make just one htaccess file to do all the forwarding?

Comment: @scabezas answer should help you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Apache with **mod_rewrite** enabled as your webserver, what you can do is create a **.htaccess** file in your application root. The content of this file should, roughly, contain something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
```

You can read more about this subject here http://www.desiquintans.com/cleanurls

Try to learn basic Regular Expressions patterns, as this is used for matching your URLs. http://regexone.com/

Comment: thanks @scabezas ! don't have time to try this right now but if this leads me to a solution I'll give you a tick  :)

Comment: Remember that this is just an introduction to the subject: there is a lot more you can do with .htaccess files! You should take a look at the .htaccess files that WordPress uses.